# How to get the text within the Span

Tags: selenium, xpath

I am trying to figure out the XPath which will retrieve the 'Love & Romance' from the following HTML

```
<div class="m-breadcrumbs no-mobile">
   <a href="/home" class="breadcrumbs-link">Home</a><span class="delimiter_breadcrumb_spacer">&gt;</span>
   <a href="/occasions/cat1000008">Occasions</a><span class="delimiter_breadcrumb_spacer">&gt;</span>
   Love &amp; Romance
</div>
```

i have tried the following **Xpath**

```
(//span[@class='delimiter_breadcrumb_spacer']/text()[last()])[2]
```

Comment: Can you add an excerpt of the HTML you're trying to process?

Comment: <div class="m-breadcrumbs no-mobile">
    <a href="/home" class="breadcrumbs-link">Home</a><span class="delimiter_breadcrumb_spacer">&gt;</span>
      <a href="/occasions/cat1000008">Occasions</a><span class="delimiter_breadcrumb_spacer">&gt;</span>
      Love &amp; Romance
     </div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract the text **Love & Romance** from the HTML you have provided you can use the `executeScript()` method following code block below (**Java perspective**) :

- [**`executeScript()`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html#executeScript-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) :

  ```
  WebElement myElement = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='m-breadcrumbs no-mobile']")));
  String myText = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript('return arguments[0].lastChild.textContent;', myElement).strip()
  ```

---

### Update

To extract the text **Love & Romance** you can also use *Java's* `split()` method as an alternative :

- [**`split()`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) :

  ```
  WebElement myElement = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='m-breadcrumbs no-mobile']")));
  String my_string = myElement.getAttribute("innerHTML");
  String[] stringParts = my_string.split("\n");
  String mypart = stringParts[5];
  System.out.println(mypart);
  ```

Comment: Unable to get the text getting below error org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Cannot read property 'textContent' of undefined

Comment: @user3538483 Checkout my updated code and let me know the status

Comment: @ DebanjanB taken the updated code and getting the  org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Cannot read property 'textContent' of undefined  Error

Comment: @user3538483 Checkout my updated code and let me know the status

Answer (score 1):

Try to use below code to get required text node:

```
WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div.m-breadcrumbs.no-mobile")));
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
String loveRomance = jse.executeScript("return arguments[0].lastChild.textContent;", myDynamicElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all child from div and after use that div.

```
WebElement a = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='m-breadcrumbs no-mobile']"));
List<WebElement> b = a.findElements(By.xpath("./*"));

for(WebElement aux : b) {

    JavascriptExecutor jsExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    jsExecutor.executeScript("arguments[0].parentNode.removeChild(arguments[0])", aux);

}

System.out.println(a.getText());
```